# C - Has Time Passed

Tags: c

I'm making a game modification for Grand Theft Auto V. In this modification, I play an animation, but I also want this animation to stop after 8 seconds.

I will have to calculate the ingame time and see if 8 seconds have passed (`GET_GAME_TIMER()` outputs the game time in milliseconds):

```
int tic = GET_GAME_TIMER();
int toc = 1;

if (toc&&((GET_GAME_TIMER()-tic) > 8000)) {
     // stop animation
     toc = 0;
}
```

But that does not work: The animation keeps on looping and it won't stop.

Does anybody else have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: _"that does not work"_ is not a problem description. What happened?

Comment: @underscore_d I'm sorry. The animation keeps on looping and it won't stop.

Comment: There is no loop in your snippet.

Comment: I suppose this depends on how the modification system works in this game. Does your code run as a function that gets called from time to time from the main program to make some decisions, or does it run as a distinct thread simultaneously with the rest of the game? Most operating systems have a system call for sleeping a set amount of time, just because the OS has access to timer hardware and can do it more effectively than the application program by itself. Possibly there's something similar in games too, since they are likely have other work while your code runs.

Comment: Use OS specific functions for idle delays (e.g. on Linux [nanosleep(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/nanosleep.2.html) or [usleep(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/usleep.3.html) or maybe [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)...) or something related to your event loop (or GUI toolkit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
if (toc&&((GET_GAME_TIMER()-tic) > 8000)) {
```

you check immediately after setting `tic` to a clock value if 8 seconds have passed. Unless the computer is *very* slow, that will not happen.

Doing a *while* on the opposite condition will work

```
while (toc && (GET_GAME_TIMER()-tic) <= 8000)) {
    // nothing, just wait
    // or you could use that time to do some quick tasks
}
toc = 0;
```

waiting in a loop until 8 seconds passed.